# ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_sync' from 'fsspec.asyn'

Tags: python-3.x, classification

I am getting the following error while using `simpletransformer` library on Saturn cloud.

```py
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_sync' from 'fsspec.asyn' (/srv/conda/envs/saturn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py)

I am not getting this error while using Google Colab.

I tried to install older versions of `s3fs`==0.5.1 and `fsspec`==0.8.4 but it's not working.